# Rewrite old mediawiki URL pattern to short URL format

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mediawiki

We have been running a mediawiki installation for some years now. During an upgrade to a newer version, we decided to switch to the [short url](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache) pattern wikipedia uses. This is working fine.

So our config file now looks like this

```
  # Enable the rewrite engine
  RewriteEngine On

  # Short url for wiki pages
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [NC]
```

As specified in the documentation for mediawiki.

But we have some old URLs floating around other places, which we would like to support still.

The old URL would look like this:

```
wiki.domain.com/wiki/Index.php/articlename
```

Now this URL looks like this:

```
wiki.domain.com/wiki/articlename
```

But using the old URL, now just gives a page not found.

We have tried using an [online htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) to find the correct RewriteRule. And we get it to work there. But not when using it in on our apache server config.

Tried with this rule, right after RewriteEngine On:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(/|$) /$1 [R=301,NC,NE]
```

Which is supposed to redirect the user to a new url. But we still get the page not found error, and the URL still looks the same.
Is our new rewrite rule wrong, or might there be something else wrong in the apache config. Will provide the config file if need be.

Comment: It is possible that it's easier to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), as this question is not a programming question so much as a question about server configuration

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll try over at Server Fault. Should I delete this post, or link to the new issue at Server Fault? So people having the same problem can find it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php\/(.*) $1$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Select the parts before and after index.php and store them using (). Using $1 and 2 to create a new URL string. I'm sure there are better solutions, but this works too.